# Where are Deus Ex saves stored?

Tags: deus-ex

I'm trying to play Deus Ex (NOT Human Revolution), but it recently developed a major bug that refuses to let me see anything on the screen. I'm thinking about just uninstalling the game but I want to keep the saves. Where does the game store its save files? I'm pretty sure they are not on the steam cloud, due to how old the game is, but there are no saves in the My Games folder.

Comment: make sure you update your video card driver. I had the same problem with deus ex HR. Updated my driver and all was well. did not lose any saved game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the Deus Ex game folder in a folder called `Save`.  If you are using Steam, you'll have to find the game within your ~\steamapps\common folder depending on where you installed Steam.

Answer (score 1):

In the `steamapps\common\Deus Ex\Save` was only an empty textfile on my system, the actual saves were in `%userprofile%\Documents\Deus Ex`.